# hovering on an anchor tag to make an unodered list visible ~ not working

Tags: html, css, hover

I am getting a problem when hovering on a link. the unordered list .shownav is not displaying. I am not sure if have declared the correct selector in my CSS. please help.

```css
.shownav {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #FFB600;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  right: 20px;
  top: 45px;
  min-width: 20%;
  border-radius: 20px 0 15px 10px;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.shownav li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.promainlink:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFB600;
}

.promainlink:hover .shownav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainnav">
  <ul class="mainul">
    <li>
      <span class="promainimg"><img src = "./images/profilepic.jpg" alt="" 
    style="border-radius:17px;height=26px;width:26px"></span>
      <a class="promainlink" href=""> User <i class= "glyphicon glyphicon- 
    triangle-bottom"></i></a>
    </li>

    <ul class="shownav">
      <li><a class="navlinks" href="">View my Profile</a></li>
      <li><a class="navlinks" href="">Account Settings</a></li>
      <li><a class="navlinks" href="">Sign Out</a></li>
    </ul>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Can anyone tells me whats wrong with my CSS? any help will be appreciated.

Comment: your html is not valid

Comment: @TemaniAfif you are correct. i just moved the .shownav inside the anchor tag and added a + symbol before the element on my css and it worked.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Voting to Close as this question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been solved. thanks for all your help. I very much appreciate it.

i have solved the problem on the issue of the ul not displaying by just rearranging the html itself. i simply just put the unordered list .shownav inside the anchor tag. i guess i have to go back to basics and understand the css selectors reference in w3school.

here is how it looks.

```
<div class="mainnav">   
<ul class="mainul">
    <li>
        <span class="promainimg"><img src = "./images/profilepic.jpg" alt="" 
style="border-radius:17px;height=26px;width:26px"></span> 
    <a class ="promainlink" href=""> Waduhek <i class= "glyphicon glyphicon-triangle- 
bottom"></i>
    <ul class="shownav">
    <li><a class = "navlinks" href = "">View my Profile</a></li>
    <li><a class = "navlinks" href = "">Account Settings</a></li>
    <li><a class = "navlinks" href  = "">Sign Out</a></li>
   </ul>   
    </a>
</li>


</ul>
</div>   

.shownav{
display:none; 
position: fixed;
padding: 20px;
border: 2px solid #FFB600;
background:#1a1a1a;
right: 20px;
top: 45px;
min-width: 20%;
border-radius: 20px 0 15px 10px;
z-index:99999;
}

.promainlink:hover + .shownav{display:block;}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this

```
.mainul > li:hover + ul.shownav { display:block; }
```

Comment: thank you for the sharing your answer. i did this trick but it was not what i was wanted to do.i only need the hover to function when the cursor hits the anchor tag, not on the list cause it has width and margin.

Answer (score -1):

You should learn about `CSS Selector`

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

```css
.shownav {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid #FFB600;
  background: #1a1a1a;
  right: 20px;
  top: 45px;
  min-width: 20%;
  border-radius: 20px 0 15px 10px;
  z-index: 99999;
}

.shownav li {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.promainlink:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFB600;
}

.promainlink:hover + .shownav {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="mainnav">
  <ul class="mainul">
    <li>
      <span class="promainimg"><img src = "./images/profilepic.jpg" alt="" 
    style="border-radius:17px;height=26px;width:26px"></span>
      <a class="promainlink" href=""> User <i class= "glyphicon glyphicon- 
    triangle-bottom"></i></a>
      <ul class="shownav">
        <li><a class="navlinks" href="">View my Profile</a></li>
        <li><a class="navlinks" href="">Account Settings</a></li>
        <li><a class="navlinks" href="">Sign Out</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for sharing your answer! yes i will definitely go back and do some reading on w3school regarding selectors.